# Keeping database-oriented test suites uptodate

Tags: c#, java, .net, database, unit-testing

Consider an automated unit test suite for a database-centric service.  Many small parts can be unit tested without any database connection whatsoever, but it is also useful to be able to plug in a real database snapshot (or snapshots) and execute larger, integration scenarios against it.  Some key tests thus include a form of a pre-execute and post-execute data snapshots that is separate from the test code itself.

The service evolves fast and so does the database schema.  This constantly invalidates test data and it becomes challenging for developers to keep the test suite up to date without letting defective behavior creep into the updated snapshots.

Typically it is not even possible to execute a newer version of the service against the old (test database) schema; this is solvable by having two layers of database snapshots, one for initialization (test input) and another one used purely for checking (for example, expected test output).  The initialization schema/data can then be upgraded automatically, together with the application, but obviously not the expected output data.

I have been through this a few times, but I would appreciate links to more reading on the topic as well as people's experiences, technologies, and methodologies, especially in the context of Java, .NET, and possibly pure database environments.

This question is intentionally somewhat broad because I do not know what I will learn from it, but here is also a narrower version of it:

**Is there any widely used Java or .NET framework that makes it easier for a developer to tell schema differences from behavior (data) differences and update the existing test data to the new schema semi-automatically?**

Answer (score 0):

1. It's a question rather of organizing of a test suite than having a framework which monitors database changes. For example - if you use Hibernate/EJB persistence model, then before executing a test suite you can create a database from the objects mapping (for example using Hbm2Ddl). Then each test creates necessary objects via saving entities (i.e. without any direct SQL). Basically speaking, in this case you don't deal with the database directly, only though persistence layer in the application. At the end of execution the database schema is dropped.
2. On the other hand, it's a question of the process. Every database change must keep tests integrity. Not like when some people make database changes without taking care of tests integrity. Basically, any change in sources must not be accepted if it breaks tests, regardless it's code or database structure changes.

In other words, there should be a certain discipline in the development process + proper test environment set up and working via a persistence layer (i.e. not a test database which is a dump of a production database with tests without or with minimal set up/teardown).

Comment: 1. I like your approach in an interesting special case.  It is very appealing as long as the service is the sole owner of the database.  Other times, the database is created by and partly populated by agents other than the service or group of services that the test suite aims to cover.  When the technologies are too heterogenous, some mock structures of other modules, or test data generated by other objects, have to be somehow maintained.  2. This is generally true, but how do I make it easier for people to update a test suite whose technology may be different from theirs?

Comment: Do you use some test integration tool like TeamCity or Bamboo? In this case people will receive notifications that tests are broken (i.e. authors of changes that caused that). And it can be very quickly escalated to a person who is responsible or can fix the tests (or code).

Comment: We use pre-commit and post-commit TeamCity and some similar home made frameworks.  The problem I have with this is that it is far too easy to upgrade the test suite incorrectly (when the bulk of the difference is as expected, looks correct, it is tempting to declare the whoe actual result as correct).  This is only a problem when a single change invalidates a hundred of test cases and manual inspection of each case and each changed row of data is not quite realistic.